# p5js Moving Circles Collisions Detection

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have made a simple sketch where 4 circles are moving at a given speed. I want to change the fill color when any of the circles touches another circle.

I think the problem is that I am initializing the x and y values for ellipse in my constructor object which I need to update as the circle moves, but I am not sure how to do that.

```js
// Declare objects
let bubble1;
let bubble2;
let bubble3;
let bubble4;
var centDistance;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  // Create objects
  bubble1 = new Bubble(50, 0, 2);
  bubble2 = new Bubble(50, 2, 0);
  bubble3 = new Bubble(50, -2, 0);
  bubble4 = new Bubble(50, 0, -2);

}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  bubble1.display();
  bubble2.display();
  bubble1.move();
  bubble2.move();
  bubble3.display();
  bubble3.move();
  bubble4.display();
  bubble4.move();

  var d = dist(bubble1.x, bubble1.y, bubble2.x, bubble2.y);
  if (d < bubble1.r + bubble2.r) {
    bubble1.changeCol();
    bubble2.changeCol();
  }

}

class Bubble {
  constructor(r, xSpeed, ySpeed) {
    this.x = width / 2;
    this.y = height / 2;
    this.r = r;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    this.fillColor = color(255);

    this.move = function() {
      if (this.x > width / 2 + 200 || this.x < width / 2 - 200) {
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
      }
      if (this.y > height / 2 + 200 || this.y < height / 2 - 200) {
        this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
      }
      this.x += this.xSpeed;
      this.y += this.ySpeed;
    }

    this.display = function() {
      fill(this.fillColor);
      stroke(255);
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, 2 * this.r);
    }

    this.changeCol = function() {
      this.fillColor = color(0);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the animation starts both circles are colliding, bubble1 and bubble2 in this example.

then you change the color to black inside your `changeCol` function and they both turn black and then stay that way indefinitely.

Your code is working the problem is that `this.fillColor` will not be re-initialized every re-render since you've instanciated your objects inside the setup function, so you have to re-paint the circles when they're not touching one another.

```
  if (d < bubble1.r+bubble2.r) {
    bubble1.changeCol(255);
    bubble2.changeCol(255);
  } else {
    bubble1.changeCol(0);
    bubble2.changeCol(0);
  }

  this.changeCol = function (col) {
      this.fillColor = color(col);
  }
```